# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<int>' exception in flutter database creation

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new in flutter application development. In my flutter application, I create a database using path provider plugin and SQFLite. But it is not working, it shows an exception message 
type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

I add my code here

```
 static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "tododatabase.db");
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return ourDb;
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE TodoList(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, todoText TEXT)");
    // print("Table is created");
  }

//insertion
  Future<int> saveTodo(Todo todo) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int res = await dbClient.insert(" TodoList", todo.toMap());
    return res;
  }
```

please help me. give a suggestion, please. Thanks in advance.

```
0631/com.stunntech.fluttertodoapp E/flutter: [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
                                                                   type '(Database, int) => void' is not a subtype of type '(Database, int) => Future<dynamic>'
                                                                   #0      DatabaseHelper.initDb (package:flutter_todo_app/database/database.dart:29:64)
                                                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                                                   #1      DatabaseHelper.db (package:flutter_todo_app/database/database.dart:20:17)
                                                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                                                   #2      DatabaseHelper.saveTodo (package:flutter_todo_app/database/database.dart:40:26)
                                                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                                                   #3      _MyTodoListState._submitTodo (package:flutter_todo_app/todo_list.dart:144:30)
                                                                   <asynchronous suspension>
                                                                   #4      _MyTodoListState._showAlert.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_todo_app/todo_list.dart:97:19)
                                                                   #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
                                                                   #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:161:9)
                                                                   #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:94:7)
                                                                   #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
                                                                   #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
                                                                   #10     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
                                                                   #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
                                                                   #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
                                                                   #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
                                                                   #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
                                                                   #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
                                                                   #16     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:13)
                                                                   #17     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:5)enter code here
```

this is the log i get.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);

Comment: Where does `openDatabase()` come from?

Comment: it's from the Database class

Comment: It's likely the problem lies there.

Comment: but the Database class is a default class. how can I edit there? I refer to many examples. Everyone takes the same way. But it not working for me.

Comment: Then create a bug report in https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Future that returns type database for your initDB() method:

```
Future<Database> initDB() async {
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, "event.db");
var theDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
return theDatabase;
}
```

A complete example is here:

https://github.com/dazza5000/austin-feeds-me-flutter/blob/master/lib/data/event_database.dart

```
class EventsDatabase {
  static const EVENT_TABLE_NAME = "event";
  static final EventsDatabase _instance = EventsDatabase._internal();

  factory EventsDatabase() => _instance;

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDB();
    return _db;
  }

  EventsDatabase._internal();

  Future<Database> initDB() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, "event.db");
    var theDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDatabase;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE " + EVENT_TABLE_NAME + " ("
        "id STRING PRIMARY KEY, "
        "name TEXT, "
        "time INTEGER, "
        "description TEXT, "
        "url TEXT, "
        "photo TEXT, "
        "lat DOUBLE, "
        "lng DOUBLE)");
  }

  Future closeDb() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: changed my code as you mention. But the same error shows again.

Comment: Please post the logs, exact exception, and line number. You issue might be on the insert statement.

Comment: I add the log I get in my question. can you please check.

Comment: If you changed the code, please put the updated code too. Thank you.

Comment: can you update onCreate to return void "void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async"

Comment: I changed my code in that way also, but the same exception shows. when calling the openDatabase() method it returns an integer database id. that time the exception shows.

Comment: Will try it on a real device tonight.

Comment: I tested the application using my mobile phone, in that time also got the same exception.

Comment: I wonder if you solved the problem because I got the same issue @Rosemary

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate()` function should be of type `void` (instead of `Future`) and should be `async`!